# How to fit equation of the form y=ao+a1logx+a2log(2/x)

Tags: matlab, equation, data-fitting

I have an equation of the form `y=ao+a1logx+a2log(2/x);` Is there away to fit this kind of equations?
 I tried to use `polyfit` but finding the coefficients `ao`,`a1` and `a2` is difficult for me.

Please Help me.

Answer (score 4):

What toolboxes are available to you?

The easiest way would probably be the cftool. (Type it into your command window) if you have the curve fitting toolbox. But polyfit should do as well.

The main problem I see: Your coefficients are not independent of one another. Because `log(2/x)` is equal to `log(2) - log(x)` your equation becomes:

```
y = ao + a1*log(x) + a2*log(2) - a2*log(x);
```

which is equivalent to:

```
y = bo + b1*log(x);
```

Try that one.

Comment: +1, As pointed out, polyfit will suffice here. B=polyfit(log(x),y,1). In the end, you cannot recover a1 and a2 uniquely, since the terms are not independent.